# Run javascript function from the code behind in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

On my code behind I have a search function and I want to call some javascript at the beginning of it and at the end.

For do this I've tried several ways but no one work !

Here what I've tried :

this :

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), string.Empty, "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';</script>");
```

this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Wait", "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';", true);
```

In despite, I wrote a function on the .aspx :

```
function wait() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display = document.getElementById('light').style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = document.getElementById('fade').style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

And try to call it as this :

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Wait", "<script>wait();</script>");
```

And this :

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Wait", "<script>wait();</script>");
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

I call  the function here, the one in the `if` runs and the other in the `else` doesn't

```
if (someTest())
{
    this.someControl.CssClass = "alert_Class";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script>noCriteriasEnter();</script>");
    this.someControl.Focus();
    return;
}
else
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Wait", "<script>wait();</script>");
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The best is coming : when I call the function at the end of the C# function (code behind) it runs !!!

Comment: Do you understand that C# is running on the server-side, and JavaScript is running on the client side? This is important.

Comment: What error do you get? Is javascript rendered to html?

Comment: STOP ! I am of the opinion that there are very few reasons you should need to to this. Instead just wire up client side events with javascript. From what I can see you are not doing anything that you need the server side for.

Comment: Just before it I launch another function like this `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script>noCriteriasEnter();</script>");` and it works perfectly...

Comment: For the second when I put a `debugger;` in the javascript it don't raise, so I don't handle the function.

Comment: This JS code will execute immediately as the page is loaded. So it won't run before/after the undescribed search function (is the search function server side c#? client side Js?) The wait() function most likely failure point is the elementId, especially if "light" or "fade" are server side ids, which get munged by the time they become HTML. (Which would be useful to see as well)

Comment: Is actual javascript rendered to the page (i don't ask if it's executed)? Please try to search for javascript code you write in html returned.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. I have done this before. 
The question is are you using the SCRIPTMANAGER in your client-side code. Just writing scriptmanager in the code behind wont work.

DO you have this line in your HTML anywhere?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smCharts" runat="server" />
```

If not then please do some research on this and add this to your markup

Comment: Yes, I have an instance of a ScriptManager on my MasterPage

Comment: Can u add your HTML too, so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: The declaration of my SM ? here it is `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">`.

Comment: I would need to see more than that. Post the full HTML code in you question

Comment: or post it in a fiddle and paste a link to it

Comment: The problem doesn't come from my HTML code, I'm sure of that because the other javascript function runs.